# Why do I keep getting this error when using dotnet run?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket, ws

I'm hosting a rbx rev and I keep getting this error when running the application part of the website and I've tried many things but I can't get it to work!

I tried turning off my firewall, and disabling my antivirus. I also tried to look around in the code it was running for problems but none I could find. I expected it to process the application and accept it and what happened was it gave me this error

> [info] ConnectionManager got error in ws connection Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>
> Connection id "0HN17IBGMV6UU", Request id "0HN17IBGMV6UU:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:3185)
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken) at Roblox.Website.Middleware.FrontendProxyMiddleware.ProxyRequestAsync(String url) in C:\Users\august\Documents\ecs\ecsagaun\services\Roblox\Roblox.Website\Middleware\FrontendProxyMiddleware.cs:line 109 at Roblox.Website.Middleware.FrontendProxyMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext ctx) in C:\Users\august\Documents\ecs\ecsagaun\services\Roblox\Roblox.Website\Middleware\FrontendProxyMiddleware.cs:line 186 at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) at Roblox.Website.Middleware.ApplicationGuardMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext ctx) in C:\Users\august\Documents\ecs\ecsagaun\services\Roblox\Roblox.Website\Middleware\ApplicationGuardMiddleware.cs:line 394 at Roblox.Website.Middleware.CsrfMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext ctx) in C:\Users\august\Documents\ecs\ecsagaun\services\Roblox\Roblox.Website\Middleware\CsrfMiddleware.cs:line 207 at Roblox.Website.Middleware.RobloxPlayerCorsMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext ctx) in C:\Users\august\Documents\ecs\ecsagaun\services\Roblox\Roblox.Website\Middleware\CorsMiddleware.cs:line 46 at Roblox.Website.Middleware.SessionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext ctx) in C:\Users\august\Documents\ecs\ecsagaun\services\Roblox\Roblox.Website\Middleware\SessionMiddleware.cs:line 170 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.Pr ocessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
>
> [info] ws connection is in state Closed, so we are re-connecting
> [info] ConnectionManager got error in ws connection Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: Could you kindly check the port status by using the command, like `netstat -ano | findstr "3185"` ？

Comment: @JasonPan https://pastebin.com/ykHgdNXJ

Comment: As you shared, port 3185 is not listening. So you need to share more relevant code to check this issue.